# codeigniter get URL after ajax

Tags: codeigniter, url

I am trying to get the URL i see on my browser after i do an ajax request but the problem is that it changes the URL with the Ajax URL.

ex.

i am on `domain.com/user/username`

and the ajax URL that i call is in `domain.com/posts/submit`

when i echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] on the posts controller in submit function it will display the second URL and not the first... how can i assure and get the first inside the ajax function that its 100% valid and not changed by the user to prevent any bad action?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i used javascript for it and it seems to work... hope not to have any problems in the future with it...

ps: i dont get why my other answer was deleted.. thats the answer anyway.

Answer (score 0):

There is [HTTP_REFERER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) but I don't know if that works for javascript requests. Another problem of this: It won't work for all browsers.

**You could try the following:**

1.) As the user visits `domain.com/user/username` the current URL is saved with a token - let's say `5299sQA332` - into the database and the token is provided through PHP to Javascript

2.) The ajax request will send this token along with the other variables needed to the controller through POST

3.) In your ajax controller you search the database for the given token `5299sQA332` and there you have your first URL and you can be damn sure, that it hasn't been manupulated

:)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to make sure the ajax call is coming from the page it is supposed to be on? In that case just pass a token with the call.

In the controller function set a token variable in session;

```
public function username() {
  $this->session->set_userdata('ajax_token', time());
}
```

Then in the view with the js;

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/user/username',
    type: 'post',
    data: 'whatever=bob&token='+<?php echo $this->session->userdata('ajax_token'),
    success: function( data ) {

  },
     error: function( data ) {

  }
});
```

Then in you form validation, do a custome callback to check they are the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at CodeIgniter's [Input Class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html) ?

```
$this->input->get('something', TRUE);
```